# Proving $T_0$ is a topological property

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau_1)$ be homeomorphic topological spaces. Show if $(X,\tau)$ is a $T_0$ space then $(Y,\tau_1)$ is $T_0$ space.

**My attempt**:

If $(X,\tau)$ is a $T_0$ space and $x,y\in X$ $\exists\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ such that $x\in\mathscr{U}$ and $y\in\mathscr{V}$ such that $\mathscr{U}\cap\mathscr{V}=\emptyset$.
It could be also inteperted as $|\mathscr{U}\cap\{x,y\}|=1$.

If $f:X\to Y$ defines a homeomorphism, then $f(\mathscr{U})\in\tau_1$ once $\mathscr{U}\in\tau$. Since $x\in\mathscr{U}$ and $f$ is a bijection then $f(x)\in f(\mathscr{U})$. By the same argument $f(y)\not\in f(\mathscr{U})$.
Then $|f(\mathscr{U})\cap\{f(x),f(y)\}|=1$.

**Question**:

Is my proof right? If not. Which are the mistakes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are typos in the first line of your attempt, and I'm not sure what you mean. The stuff before the typo with the "cap" makes it seem like you're talking about a $T_1$ or $T_2$ space. The alternative interpretation looks right; your $\scr{V}$ should not play any role, as it does not here. I think your argument after that is fine, but you need to indicate how you conclude that $\left(Y, \tau_1\right)$ is a $T_0$-space (using the bijection of open sets and the bijection of points given by the homeomorphism).

Comment: @SamStreeter Thanks for the comment, I have just corrected the mentioned typos.

Comment: The existential quantifier is still a little jarring, and that condition is the $T_2$ (Hausdorff) condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start with $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ distinct. Then there are unique $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $f(x_1) =y_1$, $f(x_2) = y_2$ as $f$ is a bijection.

$X$ is $T_0$ so there is some open $U$ in $X$ such that, say, $x_1 \in U$, $x_2 \notin U$. But then $V:= f[U]$ is also open in $Y$ ($f$ is an open map) and so $y_1 = f(x_1) \in V$ and $f(x_2) \notin V$ (or else $x_2 \in f^{-1}[V] =U$ quod non).

So $Y$ is $T_0$.